# How do I know the number of bits in a byte?

Tags: byte, bit

What is the formula for calculating the number of bits in a byte? What external resources can I find more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 8 bits in a byte. Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) for more information. Please do research before posting a question. This could have been easily googled.